# SELECT statement testing max values

Tags: mysql, select, max

I'm trying to get the ID where the Upper value is less than/equal to a given value.

```
myTable
(`ID`, `Lower`, `Upper`)
(1, 1, 9),
(2, 10, 49),
(3, 50, 99),
(4, 100, 499),
(5, 500, 999),
(6, 1000, 4999),
(7, 5000, 9999);
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM myTable
WHERE Lower>=3 AND Upper<=3;
```

and

```
SELECT ID 
FROM myTable
WHERE Upper<=3
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

and

```
SELECT ID 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY ID HAVING MAX(Upper)<=3 
ORDER BY MAX(Upper);
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable t1
WHERE  t1.Upper <= (
      SELECT (MAX(t2.Upper))
      FROM   myTable t2
  );
```

all of which return empty rows.

The option:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM myTable
WHERE Upper<=10
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

works where the test value is greater than 9...

Can anyone suggest a solution that might work?

Comment: I suspect that your `Upper` column is of a string datatype, and so comparisons are performed lexicographically?

Comment: Is this all your table data?  If so, your `Upper` value is never less than 9 in your test data.  So anytime you try `Upper <= 3` you will never get results. And is why `Upper <=10` returns one row. If you tried `Upper <= 499' you would get 4 rows back.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I get 4 rows back and just use the first row.

Comment: No, all the values are INT datatype.

Comment: @JaneAlford . . . What value do you want returned for `3`?  There is no row in the table that meets your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax on

```
 SELECT ID 
 FROM myTable
 WHERE Upper<=3
 ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Works just fine on MYSQL? double check for spelling errors or syntactical errors perhaps?

Comment: I'm using a workaround right now, if no result then I'm getting all the data and using the first row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return NULL where there is no match instead of "no rows", you can try something like:

```
SELECT max(ID) 
FROM myTable
WHERE Upper<=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it now - you want the id of the maximum `Upper` value, as long as it is less than or equal to your "test" value.  Is that correct?

```
select id
from myTable
where Upper <= X
order by Upper desc
LIMIT 1;
```

So if X = 9 you would get `ID: 1`

If X = 10 you would also get `ID: 1`

If X = 163 you would get `ID: 3`